# Bitbucket PR builder Job is not getting triggered

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Jenkins version: 2.107.2
Bitbucket PR builder plugin version: 1.4.26

I am trying to setup a Bitbucket PR buider, but my Job is not getting triggered when a new PR is created (or) when the comment "test this please" is updated in the open PR. Here's my config:

[image]

I see a below NullPointerException in the jenkins logs @ /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log.

```
May 27, 2018 4:34:59 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started PersistentMaster-Worker
May 27, 2018 4:34:59 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished PersistentMaster-Worker. 0 ms
May 27, 2018 4:35:01 PM bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.ApiClient getAllValues
WARNING: invalid response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:581)
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.ApiClient.getAllValues(ApiClient.java:207)
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.ApiClient.getPullRequests(ApiClient.java:105)
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketRepository.getTargetPullRequests(BitbucketRepository.java:94)
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketPullRequestsBuilder.run(BitbucketPullRequestsBuilder.java:37)
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketBuildTrigger.run(BitbucketBuildTrigger.java:292)
at hudson.triggers.Trigger.checkTriggers(Trigger.java:278)
at hudson.triggers.Trigger$Cron.doRun(Trigger.java:226)
at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:51)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help on this is much appreciated. Let me know what I am missing here.